# Powershell Drop the last part of a string with multiple "."

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I'm trying to do a regex expression in powershell to get only a specific part of a string. I know a way I can do this without regex but it can definitely be more efficient with. I have a string that looks like this:

```
Some/Stuff/Here/Then.drop.last
```

Ideally, I want to write a regex that gets me just:

```
Then.Drop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PS> 'Some/Stuff/Here/Then.drop.last' -replace '.*/(.+)\..*', '$1'
Then.drop
```

- `.*/` greedily matches everything up to the *last* `/`
- `(.+)\.` greedily matches everything up to the *last* literal `.` and captures everything before that `.` in the first capture group (`$1`) - which is your string of interest.
- `.*` matches the remaining part of the string.
- Using `$1` as the replacement string then replaces the overall match - the entire input string - with what the first capture group matched.

For more information about PowerShell's `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).